# Import partials in two projects

Tags: sass, compass

Is possible load scss from other location?
Example:
Current Project = `D:/developer/bla/bla/bla`
Other Project = `C:/Documents/bla/bla/`

Comment: Have you tried it with `@import`?

Comment: Yes, of course. If you use the full path works without problems, but prefer to use a relative path

Comment: Then what are asking? If you can have a relative path between drives? Or how to share code? Or what?

Comment: What I asking is whether it is possible to use relative paths when imported a file from another project regardless of its location.

Comment: Have you tried using relative paths? (e.g. ..\styles.scss, ..\..\styles.scss) Because `@import` does support them

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the command `sass` for compilation, you can specify at this moment a root directory for imports with the flag `-i`

So in your case, you're trying to access a project in another hard drive.

Your command line will be :

```
sass --watch -I / path/to/scss/dir:path/to/css/dir
```

.. and in your `main.scss`

```
@import "/Documents/bla/bla/yourOtherSCSS.scss";
```

Now each time you save will compile your scss thanks to the `--watch`flag and your other scss file will be imported in the defined output.

According to your dir C:/ & D:/, I guess you're on Windows. If you're compiling with a software, search for configuring the `:load-path`.